# Symfony query where many to many relation exists in another array

Tags: symfony

Symfony 3: I have 2 entities: `Product` and `Category`.

`Product->categories` is a many to many relationship to the `Category` entity.

I'm trying to figure out the `andWhere` clause to filter products by an array of categories.

This doesn't work, but it gives you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$qb->andWhere('product.categories IN (:categories)');
$qb->setParameter('categories', $categories);
```

How can I write a condition to filter products with an array of categories, based on the many to many `categories` property?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to join `categories`. Then `IN` works if I pass in an array of ids.

```
$qb->innerJoin('pc.categories', 'c');
$qb->andWhere('c.id IN (:ids)');
$qb->setParameter('ids', $ids);
```